# Files are truncated while decrypting

Tags: java, encryption

I have written the following code to encrypt and decrypt files using the java crypto libraries.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

class Blowfish {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Cipher encrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        System.out.print("Enter the key: ");
        s = br.readLine();
        /*
         * Names of algorithms used "Blowfish" "DES" 64 bit key ie. 8 bytes
         * "AES" key size has to be 16 bytes ie. 128 bits
         */

        byte key[] = new byte[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() && i < 8; i++)
            key[i] = (byte) s.charAt(i);

        encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "DES"));
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("encrypted.p4e");
        CipherOutputStream cout = new CipherOutputStream(out, encrypt);

        int input = 0;
        while ((input = fin.read()) != -1) {
            cout.write(input);
        }

        out.close();
        cout.close();
        System.out.println("Starting the decryption");
        System.out.print("Enter the key: ");
        s = br.readLine();

        byte key2[] = new byte[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() && i < 8; i++)
            key2[i] = (byte) s.charAt(i);

        decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key2, "DES"));
        fin = new FileInputStream("encrypted.p4e");
        out = new FileOutputStream("test2.txt");
        CipherInputStream in = new CipherInputStream(fin, decrypt);
        input = 0;
        while ((input = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(input);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
}
```

However when I tried testing it on a sample .txt file, encryption and decryption ran error free. However the decrypted file wasn't exactly same as the original one... some of the ending part was **truncated**.

**the test file**

> test file for encryption.. checking
>   the correctness

encrypting using -> pralhad

after decryption using the key -> pralhad

> test file for encryption.. checking
>   the

Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `out.close()` on the first `FileOutputStream` for `encrypted.p4e`. That stream is wrapped by `CipherOutputStream` and the `cout.close()` will handle closing the underlying stream. By closing that underlying stream early you lose what `CipherOutputStream` has buffered for the current cipher block.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("encrypted.p4e");
CipherOutputStream cout = new CipherOutputStream(out, encrypt);
int input = 0;
while ((input = fin.read()) != -1) {
    cout.write(input);
}
out.close(); // remove this line and it works
cout.close();
```

Comment: Pralhad, this seems to be the correct answer. If you are still around, please accept it.

Comment: In addition to closing the stream CipherOutputStream finalizes the encryption which is crucial for block ciphers such as AES in a non streaming mode such as CBC

Answer (score 1):

```
key[i]=(byte)s.charAt(i);
```

Due to this fact that character size of Java is 2 bytes, I think there is a problem in casting char to byte. half of the Information will be truncated. harsh if you use other characters than first 128 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Try before you close `cout` call `flush()`:

```
cout.flush()
```

Comment: The `close()` does a flush (see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732260/in-java-when-i-call-outputstream-close-i-always-need-to-call-outputstream-flus)). The problem here is something else.