# Java writeObject() to always overwrite existing object, never append?

Tags: java, object, file-io

I want to serialize a Hashtable to a file using `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`, but I want the writer to always overwrite any existing object such that only a single object exists:

```java
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream( f);
ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
writer.writeObject( hashtable);
writer.flush();
```

The hastable is updated intermittently at runtime, so I use a helper method to persist its state:

```java
private void persistObject( Hashtable ht){
   writer.writeObject( ht);
   writer.flush();
}
```

The problem is every time I call `writeObject()`, a new hastable is appended to the file; Is there any way to just overwrite whatever is in the file so only a single object is ever persisted?

Comment: I thought this was the default behaviour of `FileOutputStream`, overwrite, not append...could be wrong :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's not the default behavior if you keep the file open; it just keeps appending.

Comment: Yep, didn't read the code that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discard file contents and start writing at the beginning of the file again, you can obtain it's channel and reposition the content. The problem is, ObjectStreams uses some internal headers, and if we want to "reset" the stream we need to account for that.

Just after instantiating the `ObjectOutputStream`, store the initial position (`writeStreamHeader` writes two shorts - which consumes 4 bytes, but better be generic than sorry) so that you can position the channel without overwriting the header.

```
final long initialPosition = fout.getChannel().position();
```

Then, every time you have to write something, skip the initial bytes (by positioning the channel), reset the stream and write your object:

```
//java 1.7
private void persistObject(Hashtable ht){
   fout.getChannel().position(initialPosition);
   fout.reset();
   writer.writeObject(ht);
   writer.flush();
}
```

```
//java 1.6
private void persistObject(Hashtable ht){
   fout.getChannel().position(initialPosition);
   fout.getChannel().truncate(initialPosition);
   writer.writeObject(ht);
   writer.flush();
}
```

As @bgp mentioned, I don't think that opening / closing the file really introduces that much overhead... Also I don't think that truncating and flushing to disk at every write is efficient, or that keeping file streams open for long periods of time is a good practice (or safe), still it was quite fun to hack the `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: Nice - was looking for that, I haven't tested but this looks like what @raffian is asking for.

Comment: @raffian. Exactly, truncate or reset the Channel position just before writing the Object.

Comment: I write to the file using your approach, but on startup I read the file; this wasn't part of the question, but if your method works, the contents should be readable using `readObject()`. I'll play around with it,

Comment: This won't work. The object stream header will be removed or overwritten.

Comment: I learned something new, even if it didn't work in this case :-D

Comment: @EJP. You were right, fixed the code so it takes the stream header into consideration. Raffian sorry for jumping the gun, you were right. But now you have one "slick" solution.

Comment: @raffian, take my updated code for a ride, now it is working.

Comment: damn, you don't quit, do you? i'll play with this tomorrow, ty

Comment: Worked nice, I update your answer to reflect 1.6 and 1.7 differences, thx again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35631/discussion-between-anthony-accioly-and-raffian)

Comment: The issue with your original code was, without `truncate()`, there's data left over if a small object is written over a larger one. `truncate()` helps to compacts and gave that extra efficiency. great solution overall, exactly what I needed

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way would be to close and reopen the file, just re-run this code inside your persistObject() method:

```
private void persistObject( Hashtable ht){
    try (ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f))) {
        writer.writeObject( hashtable);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: (...don't forget to close the stream...)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but I have to keep the file open. It's a server, the hashtable maintains critical state that changes often; want to avoid the overhead of opening/closing the file.

Comment: Gotcha - IMO that overhead is probably not worth worrying about.  On modern OSes it's going to be quite small, and often the kernel does a good job of caching information related to files that are used often (i.e. if you do this a lot, the overhead of opening and closing the file isn't much). How big is the hashtable (roughly)?

Comment: It's not big, few thousand objects

Comment: @StevenSchlansker Np, only issue is the FileOutputStream doesn't get explicitly close()ed like that...

Comment: @StevenSchlansker better practice to use explicit `flush()` and `close()`.

Comment: I don't agree, but I'm not going to get into an edit war over it... OOS.close() will close the FileOutputStream for you.  An explicit flush is not necessary.  It's harmless in this case, but can be harmful in others (e.g. HttpOutputStream)

Comment: I agree with @StevenSchlansker on this one - close() is necessary, flush() is not.  This question covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732260

Comment: Hold up - doesn't `try-with-resources` auto-close streams and stuff? isn't `close()` supplied automatically after end of the `try` block?

Answer (score 1):

You should open / write / close ObjectOutputStream in persistObject. You should not truncate file at position 0. ObjectOuputStream has a complex structure, not only objects data but a header, class descriptors etc. Truncating will destroy it resulting in  StreamCorruptedException when attempting to read it.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to close the file when you save the Object
and open it when retriving object.

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream( f);
ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
writer.writeObject( hashtable);
writer.close();
```

Comment: It is not necessary to post _another_ answer that also suggests closing and opening.