# Where is the documentation for the close without flush

Tags: java

I believe and read in many post that on Java one can call the `close` method without a previous `flush` call on any JDK descendant of `OutputStream`. Actually I always overwrite (when I need it, it was rare) `close` calling a `flush` before the final close. I would like to see some official documentation that states clearly that one can safely call `close` without `flush`.

Where is some documentation saying this?

Comment: this may help, I do see a lot of confusion around the question with no uniform answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732260/in-java-when-i-call-outputstream-close-do-i-always-need-to-call-outputstream

Comment: Some seem to specify this, like for example
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close%28%29
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html
There are also examples of the opposite:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#close%28%29

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: @Fakenick Actually FilterOutputStream does call `flush()` in its `close()` function. It is odd why the docs wouldn't mention that.

Comment: @epoch Could you please verify if what I have written is correct?

Comment: @DebosmitRay, the docs do say that FilterOutputStream calls flush, they do not, however, say that ObjectOutputStream calls flush.

Comment: @Fakenick Sorry I misread the docs. Its quite odd that they don't follow a template or something

Answer (score 2):

Very nice question! *Yes, a call to `flush()` **seems** to be made.*

Now, none of the Javadocs pertaining to [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) or the various interfaces it implements like [Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) mention anything about calling `flush()` before closing the stream. It has been like this for quite long now.

But, if you look at other `Writer` classes like [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html), [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), etc. the `close()` docs specifically state that the stream is flushed before it is closed. This is because they all implement the [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) class, and the docs there specify this behavior.

Now, your guess is as good as mine here. But, I have never faced any issues when I have not flushed before closing an stream. So, I suspect that a call to `flush()` is indeed made, most probably as a result of the `Flushable` interface.

One common trait I have found is that if a class implements the `Writer` interface, the docs invariably mention the fact that *`close()` closes the stream after calling `flush()` first*.

**EDIT!!!**

`OutputStream` being an abstract class, I dug a little deeper. I found [FilterOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) which happens to extend `OutputStream`. From the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/FilterOutputStream.java#FilterOutputStream.close%28%29) for it's `close()` method...

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
            flush();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {

        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

[BufferedOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html), `DataOutputStream`, `PrintStream` extend `FilterOutputStream` and as a result, inherit the same `close()` method. If not for all,  at the very least, **`close()` in these classes do make a call to `flush()`**.

Answer (score 0):

Followed @Debosmit Rays lead and checked the source.

- ByteArrayOutputStream does not flush in close
- FileOutputStream does not flush in close
- FilterOutputStream does flush in close
- ObjectOutputStream does flush in close
- PipedOutputStream does not flush in close
- org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable.OutputStream does not flush in close

As long as the classes that extend FilterOutputStream or ObjectOutputStream do not override the close function, the child classes of FilterOutputStream should also flush.

Comment: A few issues. `FilterOutputStream` **does** flush in the close method. `OutputStream` is abstract class; so it obviously won't have an implementation.