# Placing InputStream into BufferedOutputStream for upload into Blob

Tags: java, oracle, inputstream, outputstream

I have an InputStream that I know is a PDF that I need to use to update a Blob in Oracle.  How can I transform this stream into a BufferedOutputStream, or otherwise update the Blob with this stream information?

Note that I am *not* allowed to wrap an Oracle class in my code due to the restrictions of the code.

What I've tried so far:

I have already tried using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1574857/2188082 to connect the streams, but the result is a NullPointerError, because the OutputStream is empty.

The current Query I am trying to run:

```
pstmt = dbConn.prepareStatement("UPDATE "+ qualTable("document")+" set document_blob ="
                   +" utl_raw.cast_to_raw('"+inStream+"') where document_id = " + documentId);

       pstmt.execute();
       pstmt.close();
```

I am aware that utl_raw.cast_to_raw may not be the correct oracle method to call for an inStream read, unfortunately I am not as well-versed in Oracle as I would like to be, so I am unaware of the correct cast I should be using.

Comment: You've already been commenting on my code to copy data from one stream to another - please include what you've tried so far in your  question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PreparedStatement.setBlob(parameterIndex, inputStream, length).](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBlob%28int,%20java.io.InputStream,%20long%29)

Like setString and other setters. No OutputStream, but a length needed.

Comment: Would the parameterIndex be the location in the database?  Also, would I need to execute this statement, or would it work as-is?

Comment: Nevermind, I was reminded by rolfl that I need to inclue a ? in my PreparedStatement to make it a parameter.  Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to do this is to create a `byte[]` array and to use it to transfer the data:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // 4K buffer...
int len = 0;
while ((len = input.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
   output.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
output.flush();
```

This copies some number of bytes in each loop from the input to the output, until you run out of input.

The size of the buffer is a tunable parameter which yu should test in your environment to see what works best.

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns a null error to me because the output stream is empty.

Comment: I see that your question alludes to this. Two things: As Joop suggests, use a positional prepared statement (see `?` parameters when creating prepared statements), and also find out why the output stream is null/closed, it should not be.

Comment: Your reminder to include a ? parameter has saved the day.  Thank you both. :)