# How to connect a input stream to a output stream in Java?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, outputstream

Having a InputStream and a OutputStream. 
I want to connect them.

What I want to do is reading data from InputStream. 
And then output the same data by using OutputStream. 
This is my code.

```
byte[] b = new byte[8192];
while((len = in.read(b, 0, 8192)) > 0){
    out.write(b, 0, len);
}
```

Is there any method to connect them? 
Or is there any way to input and output data without buffer?

Comment: Why are you doing this, is the pertinent question? There is [`PipedInput/OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) but this is for fairly advanced use cases where you need inter-thread communication. If you are just dumping data across on the same thread, then your approach is fine. Question is though - where is the `OutputStream` _going_...

Comment: @BoristheSpider using a piped stream will copy from an output to an input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting an input stream to an outputstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574837/connecting-an-input-stream-to-an-outputstream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guava and Apache Commons have copy methods:

```
ByteStreams.copy(input, output);

IOUtils.copy(input ,output);
```

They don't "connect" them directly. To achieve what I am assuming you want, create an `InputStream` decorator class that writes to an `OutputStream` everything that is read.

Comment: Thanks, `IOUtils.copy(input ,output);` is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Both input and output streams are a passive objects, so there is no way to connect them without creating a Thread to copy the data from one to another.

Note: NIO has a `transferTo` method though it does much the same, just more efficiently.

You don't have to use a buffer but it likely to be very slow without one.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a NIO channel/buffer

```
try (FileChannel in = new FileInputStream(inFile).getChannel();
     FileChannel out = new FileOutputStream(outFile).getChannel()) 
{
    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);

    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buff)) > 0) { 
        buff.flip();
        out.write(buff);
        buff.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this way also need buffer.

Comment: If you are using NIO anyway, why not just use [`FileChannel.transferTo/From`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long))? It will more efficient, especially if it can ask the filesystem to do the transfer.